# I cannot figure out how to change my interface with QT Designer

Tags: qt, qt-designer

I've created a new project using [ImageViewer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-widgets-imageviewer-example.html) as a starting point, now I'd like to improve the UI adding some controls, so I've edited the `mainwindow.ui` with the QT Designer this way:

[image]

but, when I build my project it doesn't reflect my changes.
I've checked the XML in `mainwindow.ui` and it contains the widget I added.

Any clue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would appear from the asterisk at the end of the file-name in the title-bar, that you haven't saved your changes.

Comment: Quick tip, if you go to Tools > Options > Build & Run, you can select "Save all files before build." Makes it much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my fault. I've noticed that I added some code in the QWidget child class contructor that overwrited the elements defined in the UI XML.